# imageview doesn't display image

Tags: android, imageview

Imageview in my app doesn't display image but still takes space on screen. I replaced it to WebView. I found out that url of the image is misspelled. However, bitmap made by  "BitmapFactory.decodeStream" is not null. I don't understand why it is not null. Then what is it? How can I set Visibility of ImageView to "gone" when it doesn't display any image?

Comment: Can you please paste some amount of code you have tried?

Comment: Can you pls elaborate ur question with the code.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know it's not null?  Is it because it's taking up space?  If so it might be that the layout is still making it take up space.  As Shashank_Itmaster and Niki said - please post some of the code.